# Error building OpenCV in Ubuntu using cmake

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, cmake

Attempting to build open OpenCV in Ubuntu, following [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) (specifically the "Build core modules" section), and I get the following error:

> [ 71%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_highgui
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so: undefined reference to 'uuid_parse@UUID_1.0'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so: undefined reference to 'uuid_generate_random@UUID_1.0'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so: undefined reference to 'uuid_unparse@UUID_1.0'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so: undefined reference to 'uuid_copy@UUID_1.0'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_highgui.dir/build.make:122: bin/opencv_test_highgui] Error 1
> make[1](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html): *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2754: modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
> make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2

I imagine this is a missing dependency, but I'm having a hard time finding it. Anyone have a fix?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?